# Datagridview DataTable edit, update and show at a time VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datatable, datagridview

i made a data table like this :

```
    Dim DTCart As New DataTable

    DTCart.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Code", .DataType = GetType(String)})
    DTCart.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Name", .DataType = GetType(String)})
    DTCart.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Amount", .DataType = GetType(Double)})
    DTCart.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Price", .DataType = GetType(Long)})
    DTCart.Columns.Add(New DataColumn With {.ColumnName = "Total", .DataType = GetType(Long), .Expression = "Amount*Price"})

    DTCart.Columns("Code").ReadOnly = True
    DTCart.Columns("Name").ReadOnly = True
    DTCart.Columns("Amount").ReadOnly = False
    DTCart.Columns("Price").ReadOnly = True
    DTCart.Columns("Total").ReadOnly = True
```

Then i show the data table to Datagridview using `DataGridView.DataSource = DTCart`

i set the 'Amount' Column to be editable so then i can update it by editing the cell in Datagridview like this :

```
Private Sub DataGridViewCart_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewCart.CellEndEdit
    If DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString = "" Then
        DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = 0
    End If

    Dim FindRow() As DataRow = DTCart.Select("Code='" & DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value & "'")
    FindRow(0)("Amount") = DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value

    Total()
End Sub
```

The 'Total()' method is just a method to sum 'Total' Column on DataTable so i can set a specific label's text to its value like this :

```
Sub Total()
    Dim sum As Double = 0
    For Each row As DataRow In DTCart.Rows
        sum += row.Item("Total")
    Next

    LabelTotal.Text = sum
End Sub
```

Now, the problem is, when i finish editing the cell, the DataTable is Updated (i checked), but the LabelTotal.Text isn't.

The funny thing is this problem comes only the first time i edit the cell.
When i tried to edit the same cell a second time it runs perfectly, everything is updated.

Help.. :'(

sorry for my bad english

Comment: What types of number will go in the Amount column? Is the Price whole numbers only? A Double (Amount) multiplied be a Long (Price) will not produce a Long (Total). I don't see where you update the Total column when the Amount is changed. Think about the datatypes you are using. Decimal is a better choice for this kind of application.

Comment: The 'Total' Column has an expression (Amount * Price) so it updated automaticaly when i changed the amount or the price.
The number type doesn't effect much, but i did take the suggestion and changed it on my program.
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I question your comment that…

> *”When i tried to edit the same cell a second time it runs perfectly,
> everything is updated.”* … ?

In my small tests... the sum of the “Total” column always reflected the “previous” total and NOT the actual total. In other words, the `LabelTotal` always missed the last change.

The reason for this is because when the code “sums” the tables “Total” column, it is when a value in the `Amount` column CHANGES (… note … the event will not fire when the “expression” column is updated). Therefore when the user changes an `Amount` value in the grid, the grid’s `CellEndEdit` event fires and sums the `Total` column and places that value into the label… HOWEVER since the `Total` column is an “Expression” column, its value has not yet been updated and will NOT be updated until AFTER the grid’s `CellEndEdit` has exited… therefore the last “Amount” change is not calculated in the sum.

I suggest you drop the `Total` method that loops through each row and sums the values and instead let the `DataTable` do this work for you using its `Compute` method to sum the `Total` column. This may simplify the code; however it will not solve the previous issue.

In order to keep the label updated with the correct sum of the `Total` column, I suggest you call the tables `AcceptChanges()` method BEFORE calling the tables compute method. Something like…

```
Private Sub DataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles DataGridViewCart.CellEndEdit
  If DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value.ToString = "" Then
    DataGridViewCart.CurrentRow.Cells(2).Value = 0
  End If
  DTCart.AcceptChanges()
  LabelTotal.Text = DTCart.Compute("SUM(Total)", "").ToString()
End Sub
```

Lastly, I agree with Mary’s comment that you should change the `Amount`, `Price` and `Total` columns to `Decimal`. Otherwise, you will lose fractional parts.

***Edit…*** Getting the correct sum without calling the data tables `AcceptChanges()` method…

After further review, it is possible that you may not want to call the data tables `AcceptChanges` event. An example is commented in addition to the possible situation where you may be tracking the changes made. In that case, you could instead wire up the `DataTable.RowChanged` event. It will fire AFTER the expression column has been updated so the SUM should be correct. This may look something like…

```
AddHandler DTCart.RowChanged, AddressOf DTCart_RowChanged
```

Add the line above to the Forms Load event... and below the event...

```
Private Sub DTCart_RowChanged(sender As Object, e As DataRowChangeEventArgs)
  LabelTotal.Text = DTCart.Compute("SUM(Total)", "").ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow i'm speechless, thank you soo much, i really appreciate your help.

Comment: and for your question, I made a video containing the problem I'm facing here https://youtu.be/r7zi41xSsao @JohnG

Comment: If a database is being updated with a DataAdapter this might cause a problem because all rows will be changed to `Unchanged` by the `AcceptChanges` method.